# jquery replace text with image (for emoticons)

Tags: jquery, emoticons

These two lines of code work perfectly -

```
var html = $this.find('pre').html().replace(':mellow:','<img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/html/emoticons/mellow.gif">');
$this.find('pre').html(html);
```

(It finds the string :mellow: and replaces it with a specific image.)

The difficulty I'm having is in trying to turn it into something where I don't have to repeat these two lines of code 50 or 60 times. (I'm at that beginner stage where you end up writing hundreds of lines of code when you could have done it in three.)

How would you turn the above into something that can handle multiple emoticon codes (e.g., :mellow:, :lol:, etc.) and figure out the corresponding image (which will have the same name as the code, minus the ::).

Pseudo code example -

```
var emoCodes = [
    ':mellow:', ':lol:', ':ninja:'
];          
var html = $this.find('pre').html().replace(+emoCodes+,'<img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/html/emoticons/+CorrespondingImage+.gif">');
$this.find('pre').html(html);
```

Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var emoCodes = [
  ':mellow:', ':lol:', ':ninja:'
];
var $this = $("body");

emoCodes.forEach(function(code) {
  var image = '<img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/html/emoticons/' + code.replace(/:/g, "") + '.gif">';
  $this.find('pre').html(function(index, html) {    
    return html.replace(new RegExp(code, "g"), image);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>:mellow::mellow::lol::ninja:</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with using an array, since you need to look for both the emoticon code and the corresponding image you can create an array of objects:

```
var emoCodes = [
    {code: ':mellow:', img: '<img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/html/emoticons/mellow.gif">'},
    {code: ':lol:', img: '<img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/html/emoticons/lol.gif">' },
    {code: ':ninja:', img: '<img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/html/emoticons/ninja.gif">' }
];
```

Then loop through the array applying the `code` and `img` properties:

```
for(var i=0: i<emoCodes.length; i++) {
    var html = $this.find('pre').html().replace(RegExp(emoCodes[i].code,"g"),emoCodes[i].img);
    $this.find('pre').html(html);
}
```

This methods allows you to have any code apply to any image, even if the `code` is not embedded inside it's url.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Ah, I forgot JavaScripts `replace` only works for the first item using strings. Thanks for the heads up, I changed it to a regexp.